# python : import some_module through other_module

Tags: python, python-import

Why  people do

```
import os
import sys
print sys.version
```

If they can do

```
import os
print os.sys.version
```

Why double-import some  basic modules(random, sys ... lot of those ), if you already know that same modules are imported  by other modules you are already using?
Are such  calls somehow deprecated to use in python programming ?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Because you should not rely on the implementation details of another module. If the other module *stops* using `sys`, then your first module is now broken.

Importing merely creates a *reference* in the current namespace. You are not loading the module into memory twice when using the `import`, so importing a module in two different locations doesn't cost you anything.

Comment: Thank you Martijn. I `ve missed the fact, that other_module import code can be changed without my knowledge and it will break my some_module code respectively.